# doctrine2 get newly added element from ArrayCollection without triggering lazy loading

Tags: doctrine-orm, lazy-loading, symfony

So I have a `User` and `Role` entity. User can have many roles.
In my code I have something like this :

```
$role = /* ... create role */;
$user->addRole($role);
```

Somewhere else in my code , I have only access to `$user` so I want to retreive the role that was added previously. If I do `$user->getRoles()` the lazy loading is triggered and I don't want that.

So how to get the newly added role from ArrayCollection without triggering lazy loading?

**Update**

All this happens on the same request, in the second part I have only access to the $user object ($role is still in memory), this is because of some stict layers (maybe bad design).

Comment: What is wrong with the lazy loading?

Comment: An extra query is executed for no reason. In my app I have a lot of roles , it can be heavy.

Answer (score 2):

If the lazy loading is triggered you queries you should simply retrieve your user via a jointed query.

like in your query to retrieve the user:

```
$qb
->addSelect("role");
->innerJoin("user.roles","role")
```

I think it is better to do this simple solution that to try to work around for bad reasons.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I'm working in the same request, the $role I just created is still in the memory, I just want the instance back.

Comment: It is in the memory, but the others roles are why you have another request isn't it? If you really want to code around doctrine, put the created role in a variable like $addedRole and use it where you need

Comment: If it is still in memory, why would you not just use it in the variable you stored it in?

Comment: As I said , in the second call I have only access to the user. Maybe, It's a bad application design but I'm stuck with it for now.